# How to prevent my Application Form from showing up in the Task Manager Application Tab

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'll specify the reason why I want to do this as I know some people won't help as it looks suspicious.

I want to hide my form from the Applications tab in Task Manager but not the processes tab.

The application in a intranet page that the company I work for forces onto all employees desktops and they are not allowed to close it. I've removed the close button, task bar and disabled ALT+F4 but some more savvy users will use CTRL+ALT+DEL. Even those users don't tend to dig about in processes but the application tab is obvious.

Can this be done?

Comment: [SOLVED] Just don't give the application a title, and if you want to be really obscure, name the exe something ambiguous and its harder to identify in processes.

Comment: feel free to remove your question, if it does not apply anymore.